# Likes Migration From App Profile Pages to Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, branding

Earlier today we migrated away from App Profile Pages to the more traditional Pages however, we were never given an option to also migrate the Facebook Likes accumulated with the application.  The App Profile Page was deleted and replaced with the newly created community page.

Are these Likes lost to the void, or is there another way to transfer or associate them?  The page name is exactly that of the application and previous Application Profile Page - there should be no problem relating the page to the application.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Facebook's documentation on the process, it takes time (about 7 days) to see the likes migrated.

Comment: 11 days, 8 business days later, and still no migration =\.

Comment: You should contact Facebook now.

Comment: Official report has been filed!